# How to concatenate strings of numbers and then assign it to a 'long' type variable?

Tags: c, parsing, matrix, vector

I'm trying to generate a "code" that represents a serie of numerical referred information to finally print it out on console screen. Let me do a better explaination:

My app needs to store some information referred to "students in an institute". It needs to read (from keyboard):

Course (1 or 2),
Level (1 to 3),
File number (up to 8 numbers),
Name and Surname,
Year Average Calification.

I need to generate a code number that denotes the Course, the Level, and the File number. For example, a student of Course 1, Level 2, with File Number 045, will be registered as '12045'. Then I have to store it in a int long variable.

After all the information is registered, it needs to be sorted in a particular way, before printing it on screen. It all works fine but the correct generation of the code number.

My problem comes when I print that generated code number. I started treating the input numbers for Course, Level and File Number as strings, to make use of 'strcpy' and 'strcat' functions, in order to generate the code and then parse it to (long). Then, I have a complete different generated code number printed on every student. Any thoughs why this may be happening?

I'm using separate vectors and matrix related by index. I hope this is a clear and useful question. If not, feel free to ask me for a better question, or even deleting it. This is my first question. Thanks!

Reading of information from keyboard

```
printf("\nIngresar Curso (1 a 2): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(curso);
    while(strcmp(curso, "1")!=0 && strcmp(curso, "2")!=0) {
        printf("\aError. Ingresar Curso (1 a 2): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(curso);
    }
    strcpy(codalumno, curso);
    printf("\nIngresar Nivel (1 a 3): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nivel);
    while(strcmp(nivel, "1")!=0 && strcmp(nivel, "2")!=0 && strcmp(nivel, "3")!=0) {
        printf("\aError. Ingresar Nivel (1 a 3): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nivel);
    }
    strcat(codalumno, nivel);
    printf("\nIngresar N de Legajo: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(legajo);
    strcat(codalumno, legajo);
```

This is the parsing and assignment to long (that I'm not positive is working properly)

```
auxl=(int)codalumno;
    alumno[i]=auxl;
```

Comment: Why you are not showing your code?

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the question before I modify my code (it has a lot of comments and variable names on spanish) I'm translating it to post it with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use atol() function.

```
auxl = atol(codalumno);
```

Comment: I did not know about this function… I tried it and it works correctly now! Thank you very much! I'm starting to learn C language at college. And I'm glad I found the needed extra help here :)